# Problems with nditer iteration and Python3 print format

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am iterating through numpy arrays with

```
for a, b in np.nditer([a_array, b_array]):
    print("{0:.3g},{1:.3g}".format(a, b))
```

but I'm receiving `TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__`.

If I'm inserting integers instead of `a` and `b`:

```
for a, b in np.nditer([a_array, b_array]):
    print("{0:.3g},{1:.3g}".format(2, 3))
```

it works.

So I guess I have a problem with the values in `a_array` and `b_array`. Are they not interpreted as normal numbers?

Can I optimize performance if I choose read only flag in `nditer()`?

## Edit

An example

```
import numpy as np

a_array = np.array([])
b_array = np.array([])

number = float(input("Input number: "))

a_array = np.append(a_array, number)
b_array = np.append(b_array, number)

for a, b in np.nditer([a_array, b_array]):
    print("(a,W) = ({0:.3g},{1:.3g})".format(a, b))
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the values in `a_array` and `b_array`, especially given that you assume the problem originates there.

Comment: The exact values of these arrays is unimportant. Even the simplest `np.arange(10)` has this problem.

Comment: note added based on your new sample.

Answer (score 1):

`nditer` does not give you scalars, it gives 1 element arrays:

```
In [6]: for a in np.nditer(np.arange(1)):
    print(type(a))
   ...:     
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

In [7]: a
Out[7]: array(0)
```

So a plain `print(a)` does fine, but not one of these new fangled (v3) formatting expressions.  The old style works: `print('%.3f'%a)`.

`item` can be used to extract the scalar from this array:

```
print("{:.3g}".format(a.item()))
```

The 'old fashioned' iterator works  (use `zip` for 2 arrays)

```
for a in np.arange(3):
    print("{:g}".format(a))
```

generic format specs also work: `print("{!s},{!r}".format(a,a))`

```
In [59]: for a in np.nditer(np.arange(1)):
    print("{!s},{!r}".format(a,a))     
0,array(0)
```

Bascially `g` and other numeric format specs don't work with the iteration variable of `nditer` because they are arrays, not scalars.  I'm guessing it's a problem with the `np.__format__` method.  It just be using the inherited `object` version.

ps - giving some sample arrays would probably have staved off the negative votes, even if that detail was unimportant.

---

`nditer` produces `readonly` values by default.  So setting the flag doesn't change them (to scalars) or improve efficiency:

```
In [258]: for a in np.nditer(A):a[...]=1
...
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

Specifying the read/write flags is useful in contexts like this:

```
In [268]: A=np.array([0,1,2,3])
In [269]: B=np.empty((4,))
In [270]: for a,b in np.nditer([A,B],op_flags=[['readonly'],['readwrite']]):
    b[...] = a*2
   .....:     
In [271]: B
Out[271]: array([ 0.,  2.,  4.,  6.])
```

---

For your sample, a 'for zip' works, and is faster.  Reserve `nditer` for cases where you need its extra features.

```
In [274]: for a,b in zip(a_array, b_array):
   .....:     print("(a,W) = ({0:.3g},{1:.3g})".format(a, b))
(a,W) = (20,20)
```